# Flat directory path to heirarchy

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree, hierarchy, directory-structure

I have a flat list of directory paths. I want to convert that to a hierarchy.

**Input format:**

```
var paths = [
  "A/B",
  "A/B/C",
  "A/B/C/D",
  "A/B/C/E",
    "F" 
];
```

**Output format**

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "B",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "C",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "D",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "E",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "F",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

In my input ,I cannot have any parent parameter. My in progress fiddle is here - https://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/Laamg14z/2/

Thanks.

Comment: _"I am on a time constraint"_ -- this won't help you get answers faster. Instead putting all your relevant code into your question using a [mcve] will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var paths = [
  "A/B",
  "A/B/C",
  "A/B/C/D",
  "A/B/C/E",
 "F" 
];

/* Output
[{"name":"A","children":[{"name":"B","children":[{"name":"C","children":[{"name":"D","children":[]},{"name":"E","children":[]}]}]}]},{"name":"F","children":[]}]
*/

console.log(convertToHierarchy(paths).children)

function convertToHierarchy(paths /* array of array of strings */) {
  // Build the node structure
  const rootNode = {name:"root", children:[]}
  
  for (let path of paths) {
    buildNodeRecursive(rootNode, path.split('/'), 0);
  }
  
  return rootNode;
}

function buildNodeRecursive(node, path, idx) {
  if (idx < path.length) {
    let item = path[idx]
    let dir = node.children.find(child => child.name == item)
    if (!dir) {
      node.children.push(dir = {name: item, children:[]})
    }
    buildNodeRecursive(dir, path, idx + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: That fiddle didn't return the same thing as you expected in the output